# How to access disk volumes using c#

Tags: .net, disk

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
    string FileName,
    FileAccess DesiredAccess,
    FileShare ShareMode,
    IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
    FileMode CreationDisposition,
    FileAttributes FlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplate
    );
    public static byte[] Main()
    {

        IntPtr ptr  = CreateFile(@"\\.\C:", 0, FileShare.ReadWrite, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAttributes.Normal, IntPtr.Zero);
        SafeFileHandle handleValue = new SafeFileHandle(ptr, true);
        FileStream disk = new FileStream(handleValue, FileAccess.Read);          
        byte[] inBuffer = new byte[512];
        disk.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                inBuffer[i] = (byte)disk.ReadByte();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        return inBuffer; 
    }
```

Using this code I attempt to read from the volume, however I am getting this exception 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
I searched and found that this is because Windows 7 blocks direct access to volumes how can I overcome this ?

Comment: Without digging into the code, the error message suggests the user profile you are using while running the application does not have sufficient privileges (ie., not an admin which is required).  Try running program "as administrator" and see if you get the same exception.

Comment: I did as you said and still get the same exception and my user profile is administrator

Comment: @HazemAhmed - Being an administrator and running the program as an administrator are two different things.  The latter being on Win Vista and above, you will get an elevated privileges prompt

Comment: @Tommy Yes it happened but the exception appears

Comment: Are you trying to read specific LBA?